# EFM8 Sleepy Bee USB connection

Tags: microcontroller

I have a EFM8 Sleepy Bee chip (EFM8SB20F32G-B-QFP32 specifically).  I would like to connect USB for programing etc. and I assume I connect the Data+ to pin 7(P2.7 / C2D) and Data- to pin 6(RSTb / C2CK).
Is this correct?  If not any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to connect USB for programing etc. and I assume I connect the Data+ to pin 7(P2.7 / C2D) and Data- to pin 6(RSTb / C2CK). Is this correct?

No. [That MCU](https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/8-bit/efm8-sleepy-bee/device.efm8sb20f32g-qfp32) doesn't support a USB connection, so that won't work.

Since you mention programming, [the manufacturer shows the programming options here](https://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/programming-options). That MCU uses the Silicon Labs C2 debug & programming interface - ignore mentions of JTAG or SWD on that page, as they apply to other MCUs from that manufacturer.